# Trivializations which preserve orthogonal structures

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I am going to quote a passage from Bott and Tu and ask some questions:

> We now show that the structure group of every real vector bundle $E$ may be reduced to the orthogonal group. First, we can endow $E$ with a Riemannian structure as follows: Let $\{U_\alpha \}$ be an open cover of $M$ which trivializes $E$. On each $U_\alpha$, choose a frame for $E|_{U_\alpha}$ and *declare* it to be orthonormal. Let $<,>_\alpha$ denote this inner product on $E|_{U_\alpha}$. Now use a partition of unity to splice them together. This will be an inner product over all of $M$. As a trivialization of $E$, we take only those maps $\phi_\alpha$ that send orthonormal frames of $E$ relative to this metric to orthonormal frame of $R^n$. Then the transition functions preserve orthonormal frames....

What do they mean by "declare"?  How do we know we can always "take only those maps $\phi_\alpha$ that send orthonormal frames of $E$ relative to this metric to orthonormal frame of $R^n$."? ${}$${}$${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{e^1_\alpha, \cdots, e^n_\alpha\}$ be a frame in the trivialization $U_\alpha$, by declaring it to be orthornormal, it means that you define a metric $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_\alpha$ on each fiber $E_x$, where $x\in U_\alpha$ by $\langle e^i_\alpha, e^j_\alpha\rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

For the second question, assume we already has a metric $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ defined on $E$. Let $\{U_\alpha\}$ be any local trivialization of $E$. These are mapping

$$ \psi_\alpha : \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \to U_\alpha \times \mathbb R^n$$

which is linear on each fiber. Let $\{ e^1_\alpha, \cdots, e^n_\alpha\}$ be an local orthonormal basis on $E|_{U_\alpha}$. Then define 
$$L : U_\alpha \times \mathbb R^n \to U_\alpha \times \mathbb R^n,\ \ \  L(x, \phi(e^i_\alpha)_x) = (x, \delta_i)$$ 
where $\{\delta_1, \cdots, \delta_n\}$ is the standard basis on $\mathbb R^n$. Thus $\phi = L\circ \psi$ send orthonormal basis of $E$ relative to $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ to orthornomal basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: how do we know such a frame exists on $E$? Could I take at each $x$ in $U$, the inverse of the standard basis $R^n$ "back" to each fiber using $\phi^{-1}$ and then prove such a map is continuous?  That is define a frame in the trivial bundle "product" $U \times R^n$ and then prove it maps to a frame in $E$?

Comment: Sort of. In a local trivialization, you know that there is a local frame $\{f_1, \cdots, f_n\}$, then do Gram-Schmidt process to get an orthornomal frame $\{ e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$. Note that, as you said, Gram-Schmidt process is continuous in $x$. @alireza

Comment: Start on $U$, map $x$ to $ \phi^{-1}(x, e_i)=f_i$ where $e_i$ are the standard basis. Now define an inner product on each fiber by pullback from the standard one since $\phi$ is an isomorphism. This too defines a metric, does it not? No need for Gram-Schmidt . Then the map             $x  \rightarrow (x, e_i) \rightarrow \phi^{-1} (x, e_i)$  is continuous locally being composition of continuous maps.

Comment: @alireza this define an inner product on $E|_{U_\alpha}$ but not on $E$ as a whole. You need to make one using partition of unity as in Bott and Tu

Comment: yes. right. We do partition of unity next and get metric on the whole thing. Then we Gram-Schmidt and get to the orthonormal frame. We do all this because in the definition of  reduction, we need the two cocycles from the trivializations to be equivalent  $ g_{\alpha \beta} = \lambda_\alpha   g'_{\alpha \beta} \lambda_\beta^-1$ where $\lambda$ must be *continuous*  which would be since the metric  and  Gram-Schmidt is and what you did for the second question is as well. That was the whole need for keeping things continuous right ?

Comment: @alireza yes ${}{}$